# How can I query lucene based on a lucene search result?

Tags: java, lucene

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve:

- I have multiple lucene indices, each containing a subset of the same data structure (they have the same fields, but the fields may or may not be present in a document in a certain index)
- There is a global identifier that is shared between indices. Meaning, if there are 4 indices, there may be up to 4 documents sharing a single key.
- I have a single lucene query

I query all indices together using a `MultiReader` and I am able to find out which sub-index the hit is coming from using `ReaderUtil`. So far so good, but here's the problem:

In order to perform a (rather complex) merging logic, i need the documents from **all** subindices with any key that matched at least one document in the original query.

Here's an example:

**Index 1**

1: `{key: "foo", name: "Name A", something: 42}`

2: `{key: "bar", something: 2}`

**Index 2**

27: `{key: "foo", something: 2}`

**Index 3**

102: `{key: "foo", name: "Name B"}`

103: `{key: "bar", something: 999}`

Now, if I would perform a query for name `"Name A"`, I would only get **document 1 from index 1**.

What I actually need are all documents from all indices with keys that were hit in that query, which are all document with key `foo`:

- doc 1 from index 1
- doc 27 from index 2
- doc 102 from index 3

based on the original query for `name: "Name A"`.

Can I achieve this without 2 separate queries, the second being a massive `OR` based on the keys retrieved in the first? Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's how i got it to work:

use a `TermFirstPassGroupingCollector` with group field `id`, and perform a search using the actual search query (e.g. `name: Name A`)

```
TermFirstPassGroupingCollector firstPassCollector = new TermFirstPassGroupingCollector(
            "<grouping field name, e.g. id>",
            Sort.INDEXORDER,
            x);

searcher.search(query, firstPassCollector);

Collection<SearchGroup<String>> firstPassResult = firstPassCollector.getTopGroups(0, false)
```

then, use a second pass collector, and collect *all* fields within all groups, using a `MatchAllDocsQuery`:

```
TermSecondPassGroupingCollector secondPassCollector = new TermSecondPassGroupingCollector(
            fieldNaming.getIdFieldName(),
            firstPassResult,
            Sort.INDEXORDER,
            Sort.INDEXORDER,
            maxDocsPerGroup,
            false,
            false,
            false);

searcher.search(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), secondPassCollector);
```

I can now iterate over all my (matched) groups, and get all documents within each group, whether it was explicitly matched or not:

```
for (GroupDocs groupDocs : documentGroups) {

    if (groupDocs.totalHits == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    for (int doc : groupDocs.scoreDocs) {

        Document document = reader.document(doc);
        ...
    }
}
```

problem solved. make sure you handle weirdness like the first pass collector  `getTopGroups()` returning `null`.